# How to read values from a CSV file and use them to rename a file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a pdf file **test.pdf** and a *TXT/CSV* file **CSVTest.txt**.  I am trying to take the values from the *TXT/CSV* (*"1234", "this", "file"*) and within PowerShell *rename* the **test.pdf** to **1234_this_file_test.pdf**. I cannot figure out how to get this to work.  Here is what I have so far

```
$files = "C:\Work\SouthParchment"

$temp = Import-Csv "C:\Work\SouthParchment\CSV\*.txt"

#$files - ls*.csv


$files |ForEach-Object{
    $fullname = $_.FullName 
    Write-Output $fullname
    #$temp = Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter ";"
    $temp = Import-Csv "C:\Work\SouthParchment\CSV\*.txt" -Delimiter ";"
    $newname = ($temp|select -first 1)."Document Type" + ".pdf"
    #Rename-Item -Path $fullname -newname $newname -WhatIf
    Rename-Item $fullname -newname $newname -WhatIf

}
```

Comment: Where is the pdf located? Is there only one row in your csv, and are there no headers? Right off the back, I can see you trying to loop over `$files`.  Did you mean to loop over `$temp`?

Comment: the PDF and CSV are in same directory. (or can be different).  In my example just trying to get one to work but will be many.  CSV has many rows and right now a header row.  However, I can have header row removed.  also, good point, there is also a column in the CSV that will have the PDF file name.  Forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question, concatenating the columns using `-join` will give you the new name you're after based off the imported csv:

```
$path = "C:\Work\SouthParchment"
Import-Csv -Path "$path\*.txt" -Header "one","two","three" | 
   ForEach-Object -Process {
        $newName = $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -join "_"
        Rename-Item -Path "$path\*.pdf" -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    }
```

The issue comes with the following...

1. Randomness - the way you're calling your *csv*, and then renaming your *pdf*, you're assuming there is only **one** *csv*, and **one** *pdf* in your current directory.
2. The next would be the rows in your *csv*. You say you plan on doing this for more *pdf*'s but, how will it know which one to do next?

   - In other words, there is nothing to *disambiguate* one *pdf* from the next.
   - No means of saying which *pdf* should be named what from what row in the *csv*.

---

*Would suggest looking into my bullet points and coming up with a better solution on how to implement this.*

Comment: The first column in the CSV would be the name of the PDF.  Can I search and match the filename with the first column?  As for as one to one.  There will Always only be ONE CSV, but multiple PDFs

Comment: Do you mean row?